# How to fix cornerRadius in text element in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I am new to react native and am struggling to round the corners to text elements, as you can see the corners are still sticking out of the rounded border, and the same happens when I wrap the text in a view element, I don't know how to fix this. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, Touchable, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default class App extends React.Component {

 myButtonPressed(){
  Alert.alert("Logout");
}
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight 
          onPress={this.myButtonPressed}
        >
        <Text style={styles.text}> Login </Text>      
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#BB2CD9",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF"
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is wrap the text inside view component and pass all neccessary styling to the view.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {

 myButtonPressed(){
  Alert.alert("Logout");
}
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight 
          onPress={this.myButtonPressed}
        >
          <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> Login </Text>      
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  btnContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#BB2CD9",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
  }
});
```

Comment: that sort of works, you can still see a rounded line close to the corners

Comment: looks a lot better with a white border color

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TouchableOpacity` for better experience. You don't need to define border n all with `TouchableOpacity`.

Try this - [Live Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@akhtarvahid/demo)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

 myButtonPressed(){
  Alert.alert("Logout");
}
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={this.myButtonPressed}
          style={styles.hLight}
        >
        <Text style={styles.text}> Login </Text>      
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  hLight: {
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#BB2CD9",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize:20,
    color:'white'
  }
});
```

Using `TouchableHighlight` - [Live](https://snack.expo.io/@akhtarvahid/demo)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

 myButtonPressed(){
  Alert.alert("Logout");
}
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight 
          onPress={this.myButtonPressed}
          style={styles.hLight}
        >
        <Text style={styles.text}> Login </Text>      
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  hLight: {
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#BB2CD9",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 40,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize:20,
    color:'white'
  }
});
```